# как узнать используется ли в этом виджете rootNavigator?

Tags: flutter, dart

я создаю виджет в котором хочу спрятать строку. Показывать я буду эту строку только если переход был с `rootNavigator: true`. Как можно такое условие прописать?

Comment: Передать как параметр в аргументы навигатора?

Comment: @MiT, это вручную, а если так чтобы он сам знал что он перешел без `rootNavigator` или наоборот?